# Git: force push cleared all of my commits - can I get them back?

Tags: bitbucket, git

My live site was updated since my last commit, and I hadn't made any local changes, so I wanted to just push everything that's live up to my Git repo.

So I did a git push --force

Now I have no commits in my repo, other than the most recent commit.

How can I get them back?

Here's the repo if you need the link: https://bitbucket.org/nicolefurlan/us-vegweek-2014

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure which repo was pushed to where, but on any repo (local or remote) you can run `git reflog` to get the history of all previous commit states in that repo.

Use `git reset --hard <commit-id>` to restore the last good commit to `master`.

If your last good state wasn't committed at any point in time, there's no way to retrieve it.

Comment: When I run "git reflog" I only have the latest commit - it totally wiped out all previous commits.

Comment: Also, under my "Recent activity" there are many entries for "Changeset stripped from nicolefurlan/USVegWeek_2014"

Comment: @runningonplants there is no possible way to purge the reflog with a forced push. You either have never had more than that single commit, or you have done something else you're not telling us.

Comment: Hmm, that is literally all I did. I ran "git push --force" from my live server and it wiped all of my commits away. On my local environment, when I run "git reflog" I can see all of the commits, but I can't push from my local environment (hoping maybe that'll restore the commits) because it's telling me I have to pull first.

Comment: @runningonplants if your local environment is good, you can just push it back to the live server. Again, since it's not a fast-forward push, something is clearly wrong on the live server. But here you can again use a force push to push all the commits from local dev to production.

Comment: It worked, thank you. Do you have any idea how I can get my live code up to the repo - without doing a pull and without doing a force push (which apparently wipes out all of my commits when done on the live server)?

Comment: please, if you have right answer, check as solution. And you can post another question to resolve your previous comment.